# Mybatis , Adding mapper xml file to Java created Configuration

Tags: mybatis

I have a my batis (3.2.7) application, and I'm creating configuration using java code ( not xml ) as following.

```
public static Configuration getConfiguration(DataSet data) {
        if (configuration == null) {
            DataSource dataSource = getDataSource(DRIVER, URL, data.getUsername(), data.getPassword());
            TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
            Environment environment =
                    new Environment("development", transactionFactory, dataSource);
            configuration = new Configuration(environment);
        }
        return configuration;
}
```

Using above configuration sql session factory is created.

```
SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);
```

My mappers are in xml format ( I need these in xml format), and currently in same package as mapper interface. I'm using following code to add mappers.

```
configuration.addMapper(CrudMapper.class);
```

This will automatically add xml mappers which are in same folder as mapper interface ( CrudMapper). But I need to move these xml file to resource folder.  So mapper interface will be in one location, and xml mappers are in different location.
I could not found any way to add xml mappers to configuration. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably adding xml mappers to root of resource folder. `Configuration.addMapper` should work fine if you preserve package structure in resources folder so that for mapper interface `com.company.app.MyMapper` corresponding xml mapping is stored in `resources/com/company/app/MyMapper.xml`.

In this case xml mapping will be put to exactly same package during compilation.

Comment: It worked for me thx, but in my case I need to put my pappers under resourses under mybatis folder, how can we do that?