# Add xml mapper to the configuration of myBatis in the java code with path different than the interface one

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I initialized my SqlSessionFactory in java code using an environment and datasource defined within the java code as below:

```
TransactionFactory trxFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
Environment env = new Environment("development", trxFactory, dataSource);
Configuration config = new Configuration(env);
config.setJdbcTypeForNull(JdbcType.NULL);
TypeAliasRegistry aliases = config.getTypeAliasRegistry();
aliases.registerAlias("XXXAttempt", XXXAttemptDao.class);
config.addMapper(XXXAttemptMapper.class);
SqlSessionFactory factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(config);
```

my problem is that I need to add my xml mappers here but I couldn't:
I tried to use:

```
config.addMappers("config/mybatis/xxx/*.xml");
```

and

```
config.addMappers("config/mybatis/xxx/*.xml");
```

with no luck. note that config.addMapper accepts only java class

The only way that worked is to move the xml file to the same package like the interface example to ([REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152281/mybatis-adding-mapper-xml-file-to-java-created-configuration)):

```
config/com/example/mappers/XXXAttemptMapper.xml
```

but what I need is to be consistent with other projects and put the xml file in the below path:

```
config/myBatis/myDb/XXXAttemptMapper.xml
```

how to add the path for my xml file in the above location?

Comment: If you use spring(spring-boot), I propose to use the `SqlSessionFactoryBean` provided by mybatis-spring.

Comment: @Chris did you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is not provided out of the box in mybatis. The actual relation between mapper interface and mapper xml file is [hardcoded](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/builder/annotation/MapperAnnotationBuilder.java#L169) in `MapperAnnotationBuilder` class:

```
String xmlResource = type.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".xml";
```

And there is no built-in way to override this. In order to change this you need to implement your own equivalent of the `MapperAnnotationBuilder` (you can inherit most of its functionality but would need to override `parse` method in order to change call the method that would replace `loadXmlResource`):

```
class MyMapperAnnotationBuilder extends MapperAnnotationBuilder {
  public void parse() {
    String resource = type.toString();
    if (!configuration.isResourceLoaded(resource)) {
      loadXmlResourceFromCustomPlace();
      // ... continue as MapperAnnotationBuilder.parse method
    }
  }
  void private loadXmlResourceFromCustomPlace() {
    // this should be similar to MapperAnnotationBuilder.loadXmlResource
    // but load resource from some other place
  }
}
```

Now you need to make use of `MyMapperAnnotationBuilder` in your own implementation of the class similar to `org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperRegistry` (let's say you call it `MyMapperRegister`). You need to inherit from it and override `addMapper(Class<T> type)` method to use `MyMapperAnnotationBuilder`.

And the final step is to use your mapper registry implementation in the `Configuration`. There is no way to set it externally so you would need to inherit from `Configuration` and use you mapper registry:

```
class MyConfiguration extends Configuration {
  public MyConfiguration{Environment environment) {
    super(environment);
    this.mapperRegistry = new MyMapperRegister(this);
  }
```

After this you use `MyConfiguration` the same way you use `Configuration` to configure mybatis and it will load xml mappers from the place defined by the logic implemented in `MyMapperAnnotationBuilder.loadXmlResourceFromCustomPlace`.

Answer (score 0):

[MyBatis-spring](http://mybatis.org/spring/factorybean.html) supports mapper interface and mapper xml have different name. In this example, mapper interface `IMapper.java` is in package `com.example.myproject` and mapper xml is in `resources/mapper/mapper.xml`. An option is to use the `mapperLocations` property of the factory bean.

```
private DataSource dataSource(String driver, String url, String userName, String password) {
    return new PooledDataSource(driver, url, userName, password);
}

public SqlSessionFactory createSqlSessionFactory(String driver, String url, String userName, String password) throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setTransactionFactory(new JdbcTransactionFactory());
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource(driver, url, userName, password));
    factoryBean.setMapperLocations(
            new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:mapper/*.xml")
    );

    return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Notice the method `setMapperLocations` accepts `Resource` as a parameter, and here the path (using pattern) is `mapper/*.xml`.
You can using mapper interface like this:

```
 try (SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
        IMapper mapper = session.getMapper(IMapper.class);
        //execute query here
    }
```